# powercli limit new-snapshot to create one at a time

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a couple scripts to create and remove snapshots for a group of servers.  When I remove the snapshots it does it one at a time, but when I create the snapshots it tries to do them all at once which tends to overload the hosts. Does anyone know of an option that I am missing to have it create the snapshots one at a time?

Here is what I use to create the snapshots

```
get-vm -location “Test-Env” | New-Snapshot -Memory -Quiesce -Name Snap1
```

Here is what I am using to remove the snapshots

```
get-vm -location “Test-Env” | Get-Snapshot -Name Snap1 | Remove-Snapshot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use location which is a collection (probably resource pool), so it tries to do them all in one go.

The New-Snapshot command should run each one and wait it you refer to it per VM. Using RunAsync command stops it waiting for each one, default is off.

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/New-Snapshot.html

So you don't need to sleep

```
$VMS = get-vm -location “Test-Env”

foreach ($VM in $VMS)
{
    $Snapshot = $VM | New-Snapshot -Memory -Quiesce -Name Snap1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Start-Sleep` cmdlet to wait, or using do/while loop until you check the completion of the snapshot, using somthing like:

```
$VMS = get-vm -location “Test-Env”

    foreach ($VM in $VMS)
    {
        $Snapshot = $VM | New-Snapshot -Memory -Quiesce -Name Snap1
        do {
        sleep 1
        }
        until (Get-Snapshot $Snapshot)
    }
```